# Keyevent is interrupted by modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I'm working on React.js project with reactstrap and having some troubles in handling keyboard events with component which is in modal.

here's my simple code snippet

```
<Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle}>
      <ModalBody>
              <Input onKeyPress= {(e) => if(e.key === 'Enter') {//do something}} />
      </ModalBody>
</Modal>
```

When I try to add event handler to Input component and test it when modal is open, It works abnormally and

I tried add `e.preventdefault()` inside onKeyPress handler but even keyboard Input did not work on Input component.

and I tried `e.stopPropagation()`, But nothing happened.

I think Modal component is capturing keypress event. Because when I press ESC button, it dismiss itself.

I want **only Input component reacts on key press event.** How to prevent Modal component capturing key press event?

Comment: `e.stopPropagation` on the `input` event should be the way to go. You can't use that in combination with putting the input's value in the component state?

Comment: What exactly is the abnormal behaviour?

Comment: Try `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`. Of course, if u r using it